# Django Template Conditional Statement Using Dates

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to do a check on my Django template to see if the 'date_added' field for a particular post is within the last three days.

I'm trying something like this:

```
{% for deal in deals %}

{% if deal.date_added > (timezone.now ()- timezone.timedelta(days=4)) %}
    <h1>HOT</h1>

{% else %}
      do some other stuff
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

I'm getting this error: Could not parse the remainder: '(timezone.now' from '(timezone.now'

so something tells me deep inside that this is absolutely not possible to have this sort of conditional statement run from within the template---but figured i'd check.  thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Deal(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_label(self):
        if self.date > datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=4):
           return "<h1>HOT</h1>" 
        else:
           return "OLD..."
```

... then in your template

```
{% for deal in deals %}
    {{ deal.get_label | safe }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: awesome thanks this looks perfect and makes a lot of sense.  one issue--when i try it i get 'can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.date' so i assume this has to do with error in comparing two different data types.  my date_added variable is set in model like this: models.DateField(default=timezone.now).   I've tried altering the conditional to be timezone.now() - timezone.timedelta(days=4) but get same error.  any thoughts?